# Querying Database from a kernel mode driver

Tags: database, database-connection, driver, device-driver

I want to **query a SQL database from a kernel mode driver**. i found that this can be done by querying a user mode application to do the task and return the result to kernel mode driver.

But is there any direct way from kernel mode driver itself ?

Comment: Please read [this](http://download.microsoft.com/download/e/b/a/eba1050f-a31d-436b-9281-92cdfeae4b45/KM-UMGuide.doc) ... repeatedly.